# Matlab function - show doubles instead of parameter names

Tags: matlab

I have defined a Matlab function with regards to other variables. However when I print out the general form of the function it does not compute the value of the 
other parameters. How can I show their values instead of their names?

A minimal example is given below:

```
t_br = 0.0199;
Gsrv = @(s) 1/(t_br*s + 1);
disp(Gsrv) % don't want to display 't_br' but 0.0199.
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [subs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/subs.html)

```
Gsrv = @(s) 1/(t_br*s + 1);
subs(Gsrv,t_br,0.0199) % don't want to display 't_br' but 0.0199.
```

or simply

```
t_br =0.0199
Gsrv = @(s) 1/(t_br*s + 1);
subs(Gsrv) % don't want to display 't_br' but 0.0199.
```

Comment: Indeed it shows a numerical value of the parameter at hand, but in a rather inconvinient manner (199*s/1000) especially for bigger data manipulation. Is there any better alternative to this ?

Comment: @bergercookie. Try `vpa(subs(Gsrv))` for a different format if that's what you prefer. `>> vpa(subs(Gsrv))

ans =

1/(0.0199*s + 1.0)`

Comment: @bergercookie, alternative to that `>> simplifyFraction(subs(Gsrv))

ans =

10000/(199*s + 10000)`

Comment: Be careful using the symbolic toolbox for this purpose because in many cases it replaces multiplication and division with element-wise operations. Convert this function back to a function handle and you get `@(s)1.0./(s.*1.99e-2+1.0)`

Comment: `vpa(Gsrv)` is enough, `vpa(Gsrv)=1/(0.0199*s + 1.0)`

Answer (score 0):

You can get the workspace of a function handle which stores all the variables needed for that function. For example,

```
t_br = 0.0199;
Gsrv = @(s) 1/(t_br*s + 1);
f = functions(Gsrv)
f.workspace{:}
```

This is not as easy as disp showing the values.

Answer (score 0):

General case, in which **the function may have an arbitrary number of parameters**:

```
d = 5; %// desired number of digits
f = functions(Gsrv); %// function
fString = f.function; %// string defining the function
split = regexp(fString, '@\(.+?\)', 'end');
fString1 = fString(1:split); %// @(...) part
fString2 = fString(split+1:end); %// remaining part, to be passed to `subs`
fParam = f.workspace{1}; %// parameters of function
fParamNames = fields(fParam); %// names of parameters of function
fParamValues = struct2cell(fParam); %// values of parameters of function
result = [fString1 ' ' char(vpa(subs(fString2, fParamNames, fParamValues), d))]
    %// pass fString2 to `subs` to do the parameter substitutions
    %// apply vpa to use decimal representation with the desired number of digits
    %// convert that to string (with `char`), and  concatenate with fString1
```

Example:

```
a1 = 1;
b_2 = 2.3333333;
cc = -10;
Gsrv = @(x,y1,z_2) x^a1 + b_2*y1 + exp(cc*z_2);
```

produces

```
result =
@(x,y1,z_2) x + 2.3333*y1 + exp(-10.0*z_2)
```